# Springfox / Swagger not picking up annotations from library

Tags: swagger, shared, springfox

I have springfox integrated with my spring-boot application and the /swagger-ui.html is displaying my REST endpoint documentation successfully.

However, my project is structured so that the API model classes are in another project (referenced in the pom.xml) that is shared with other REST endpoints. Compiling my springfox-enabled REST endpoint omits the @ApiModel annotations from the shared library since the compiler is only seeing the bytecode from the shared library, not the source with annotations.

(I've confirmed that copying the API model source directly into my REST project does produce documentation with the ApiModel property information).

How can I solve this? Is it possible to generate json / yaml from the shared library and 'import' it into the springfox generation of the swagger HTML?

Comment: try converting the project containing API model into a faceted project as a utility. provide this to the other project as part of its build path.

Comment: That would probably work in eclipse, but we are building in Jenkins where the API model source is not available.

Comment: The `@ApiModel` annotation is [retained at runtime](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-annotations/src/main/java/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModel.java#L32). So For sure it shouldn't be lost at runtime (in the byte code).